# Parse JCR XML export in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, jcr

I received some XML files from a customer that I need to process in C#. Looking at the structure and doing some googleing it seems that this content has been exported from JCR (I haven't worked with this at all so I might be wrong).
The structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sv:node xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" sv:name="foodtruck-gruener-sepp">
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
    <sv:value>mgnl:Event</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:mixinTypes" sv:type="Name" sv:multiple="true">
    <sv:value>mgnl:hasVersion</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>6371704f-1cc4-4ab9-9298-43c9dd4f79ab</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>user name</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="email" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>info@somedomain.com</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
</sv:node>
```

How would I go about parsing this? Can this be done by just using `XMLElementAttribute` with `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: The same way you would any XML file. You can use XmlSerializer or LINQ to XML. If you want to generate strongly typed classes in Visual Studio and go to `Edit> Paste Special > Paste XML as classes`. If you have an XSD you can generate the classes from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below uses xml linq and puts results into a dictionary.  The code does not parse the xml Type attribute

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement node = doc.Root;
            XNamespace sv = node.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("sv");

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants(sv + "property")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute(sv + "name"), y => (string)y.Element(sv + "value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have to create a class with the same type of XML, that can be generated through visual studio Edit> Paste Special to deserialize it.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class node
{

    private nodeProperty[] propertyField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("property")]
    public nodeProperty[] property
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propertyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.propertyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0")]
public partial class nodeProperty
{

    private string valueField;

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    private bool multipleField;

    private bool multipleFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public bool multiple
    {
        get
        {
            return this.multipleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.multipleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool multipleSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.multipleFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.multipleFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```